# Custom js fie not working Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2.2

Currently I am working in magento2 theme part. And I have a `main.js` file which I have added via `default_head_blocks.xml` . But its having `jquery conflict`. I removed `jquery conflict using noConflict`. When I do this **my testimonial section which consists of owl carousel doesnt work**. Please tell me how to add my `'main.js'` file.

or
Can someone tell me how to include the functions in `'main.js'` on header to display the banner and drop-down menu?

Comment: Are you using PHTM for testimonial section?

Comment: yes..its an extension that I am using for testimonial. in this extension they have used Owlcarousel

Comment: You need to use require JS

Comment: for my main.js?

Comment: yes, for that JS.

Comment: This is the code which I provided in require.js file



        var config = {
            paths: [
             'js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',
             "js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js",
             "js/main.js"
    ]
};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Update your `require-config.js` file this content:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'bootstrap_min': '{{module Package name}}_{{module name}}/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
            'custom_main': '{{module Package name}}_{{module name}}/js/main.js'
    },
shim: {
    'bootstrap_min': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'custom_main': {
        deps: ['jquery']    
    }
};
```

Then You need to call that files in your `PHTML`:

```
require(['jquery', 'custom_main']);
```

And `main.js` content should be like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    '{{module Package name}}_{{module name}}/js/vendor/bootstrap.min'
], function ($,bootstrapMin) {

    "Your main.js file code put here."

});
```

If your file in theme then file should be in `app/design/frontend/{{theme package name}}/{{theme name}}/{{Module package name}}_{{module name}}/web/js/main.js` AND If your file in module then file should be in `app/code/{{Module package name}}/{{module name}}/view/frontend/web/js/main.js`.

Comment: Now I am getting this error "Refused to execute script from '{{path of js file}}'  because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: the js file is inside js folder within web but in path it just show http://localhost/testmag/pub/static/version1525520239/frontend/Package name/module/en_US/main.js

Comment: Where have you put your JS file? Please provide path.

Comment: Within frontnend/module Package name/moduename/web/js/main.js
and require.js in frontnend/module Package name/moduename

Comment: Are you trying in theme OR module?

Comment: If in theme then file should be in `app/design/frontend/{{theme package name}}/{{theme name}}/{{Module package name}}_{{module name}}/web/js/main.js` AND if in module then file should be in `app/code/{{Module package name}}/{{module name}}/view/frontend/web/js/main.js`.

Comment: trying in theme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78022/discussion-between-kunj-and-bridgit-thomas).