# Magento 2: Uncaught Error: Script error for: smartmenus

Tags: magento2, requirejs, magento2.2.4, custom-theme

I am trying to implement the navigation menu with **Bootstrap Smartmenus** but the theme does not pick up the javaScript. Can somebody help me out?

**Vendor/Name/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
      'bootstrap':'js/bootstrap',
      'smartmenus':'js/jquery.smartmenus',
      'bssmartmenus':'js/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min',
    }
  },
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
      'deps': ['jquery']
    },
    'smartmenus': {
      'deps': ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
    },
    'bssmartmenus': {
      'deps': ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'smartmenus']
    }
  }
}
```

**Vendor/Name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="head">
      <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
        <arguments>
          <!-- RequireJs library enabled -->
          <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
      <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>
    </referenceBlock>
.....
```

**Vendor/Name/Magento_Theme/templates/html/menu.phtml**

```
<?php

/**
*  General template for displaying group of blocks devided into sections
*/
// print_r($block->getRootCategories());
$categories = $block->getRootCategories();
$nosub = [];
$count = 0;
?>
<?php if ($categories): ?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav2 ">
        <div id="navbar2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php
                    $subcategories = $block->getSubCategories($_category);
                    if ($subcategories):
                        $count++;
                ?>
                <li class="<?= $count==1?'nav2firstlink':''?>" ><a href="<?= $block->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?= $_category->getName(); ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php foreach ($subcategories as $_sub): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= $block->getCategoryUrl($_sub) ?>"><?= $_sub->getName(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php else: $nosub[] = $_category; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?php if (count($nosub) > 0) : ?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav3 ">
        <div id="navbar3">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php foreach($nosub as $_cat): ?>
                <li><a href="<?= $block->getCategoryUrl($_cat) ?>"><?= $_cat->getName(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'smartmenus', 'bssmartmenus'], function(jQuery, Bootstrap, SmartMenus, bsSmartMenus) {
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('.nav2').smartmenus();
        });
      });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please let me know, how should I fix this issue.
[image: javascript error]

On further checking with the logs, found these:

```
[2018-06-27 06:40:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'requirejs' element cannot be added as child to 'head', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'requirejs' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'head' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'requirejs-config' tries to reorder itself towards 'requirejs', but their parents are different: 'head' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Name/en_US/bootstrap.js' [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Name/en_US/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js' [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Name/en_US/priceUtils.js' [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Name/en_US/jquery/ui.js' [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:20] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Name/en_US/bssmartmenus.js' [] []
[2018-06-27 06:40:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Name/en_US/jquery/validate.js' [] []
```

Looking on how to resolve this issue!!?

Comment: Why you added this code `<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
        <arguments>
          <!-- RequireJs library enabled -->
          <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
      <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>`

Comment: When I get this error, I found another similar post, on how to implement bootstrap. In order to enable the **requirejs** it's added in the default.xml. [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107763/how-to-add-bootstrap-js-in-magento2]

Answer (score 0):

Its because the path is not rendered properly. Please check this link 
[Custom js fie not working Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227605/custom-js-fie-not-working-magento-2/227611?noredirect=1#comment316503_227611)

Guess it will help you.